# Issue with rewrite rule, causing 500 errors on one server but not on another

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a .htaccess as such:

```
Options -MultiViews
#Rewrite queries from google to the right files
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /fragments/%1.html
```

On my server (a standard LAMP debian) it works flawlessly.
As soon as i upload that to the hoster (1&1) i get a 500 error, and per 1&1's own policy there is no way to inspect the error log.

Tech support took 2 weeks to answer my support request, and when they did they pointed me to a generic page describing mod_rewrite .

Can anybody spot syntactical errors in the rewrite rule/condition , and eventually offer another way of doing what that rule does?

Comment: At two weeks to answer a support request, I'd me moving elsewhere and rapidly! The idea that you can't see your own error logs is ridiculous.

Comment: 1&1 . Steer clear of these bloodsuckers!

Answer (score 0):

500 errors mean that something is wrong with server settings (500 - internal server error).

It is possible that:

1) Your server does not support .htaccess files overwriting host settings

2) Rewrite module is not enabled

3) Syntax of rewrite in your htaccess is not correct

As far as i can see your code is correct. So then possibly it is either 1 or 2 option.

I would suggest:

1) Wrap your rewrite code with below (that will check if mod-rewrite is on)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
...
</IfModule>
```

2) Remove everything from `.htaccess` and try empty one (if still 500 -- overwrite is not allowed)

3) I don't see `DirectoryIndex your_index_file` in your code. Did you omit it?

Comment: This is a professional hosting company, they do indeed support mod_rewrite and other .htaccess rules are applies successfully.

Comment: Check my edits to comment. I missed that i don't see `DirectoryIndex` in your code.

Comment: The problem seemingly lied in the fact that it didnt like to redirect to / , instead it needed a FQDN . i had to add the ? to the end of the rule to strip the query params which were now being passed on .

Comment: @user436118 Honestly never seen issue like that before

Answer (score 0):

Using the following:

```
Options -MultiViews
#Rewrite queries from google to the right files
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mydomain.com/fragments%1.html?
```

solved the issue.